# Only render angular directive after a property has been set?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a loading view that's set as the html inside the directive. Something like the following.

```
<my-directive>
    <div class="loader"></div>
</my-directive>
```

I'd like the HTML inside there to be active until some property of my directive has finished processing.

The closest thing I've found is `transclude` but I'm not sure that's really what I want.

Is there a way to avoid rendering until some arbitrary point in time?

Answer (score 0):

you can hide a html element until a property return true

```
<div ng-if="taskFinished"></div>
```

or

```
<div ng-show="taskFinished"></div>
```

both do the same think but with ng-show the hidden content are not recalculated on each unhide

Answer (score 0):

What Alainlb explained is also how I would approach the issue, show in the example below:

```
<my-directive>
    <div ng-if="loading">
        <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!loading">
        <span>Do everything in here...</span>
    </div>
</my-directive>
```

### `ng-if` and `ng-show`/`ng-hide`

I personally will **always** use `ng-if` unless there is a very good reason not to. Since `ng-if` will only render the HTML when the check has passed. `ng-hide` on the other hand will make the HTML code invisible but it is still there! When the directive is very complex, then the browser is doing pointless work calculating and rendering things the user can't even see. To me, the only time it makes sense is when you want to collapse items that you know for sure the user will open very often. Even in this case I would still consider `ng-if`, unless it takes a long time to render each time.